# Async Storage from package "@react-native-community/async-storage" not retrieving date properly in react-native

Tags: react-native, date, storage

I have the following code in react native:

```
 const handleRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
  const date = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`lastRequestDate`);

  console.log('date: ', date);

  console.log('type of: ', typeof date === 'string' ? date : '');

  const previousDate = new Date(typeof date === 'string' ? date : '');
  // const previousDate = new Date('2021-06-02T00:52:46.892Z');

  console.log('previous date: ', previousDate);
  
}, [user]);
```

When I console log **previousDate** I get `Date { NaN }` but if I console log **date**  I get `"2021-06-02T00:52:46.892Z"`. If I console log `const previousDate = new Date('2021-06-02T00:52:46.892Z');` I get the correct date. However if I replace the string by **date** variable the error appears (`Date { NaN }`) (`const previousDate = new Date(typeof date === 'string' ? date : '');`)

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the condition in a variable and use that in the `new Date(...)`

```js
const newDate = typeof date === 'string' ? date : ''
 const previousDate = new Date(newDate);
```